# Reading Files in Directory

Tags: r, file, csv, directory

I am trying to read multiple data in my directory and build a data frame using and combining them. The below code helped me a lot but I want someone else, which I send the code, can use this code and can read the all files in his/her directory. This code only works for my computer apparently? Do you have any idea?

```
 all.the.files <- list.files("C:/temp",full=TRUE)
 all.the.data <- lapply( all.the.files,  read.csv, header=TRUE)
 DATA <- do.call("rbind", all.the.data)
```

Comment: You have to create a variable to store the path of the directory to read. In your code, you read `"C:/temp"` by default.

Comment: To start with, this code assumes there is a `C:/` drive, that `C:/temp` exists, that `C:/temp` is full of CSV files, and that all the CSV files are compatible with respect to `rbind()`.  You would need to be sure that all of those assumptions are true on other machines.